# jquery ui draggable nested scale containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, scale, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to have a draggable element which is inside 2 scaled elements, I have a fiddle with a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/MAEvS/671/

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
            start: function(ev, ui) {


                scale_factor = 2;



                ui.position.left = 0;
            ui.position.top = 0;
            },
            drag: function(ev, ui) {

                console.log(ui.position)
                var changeLeft = ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left;
                var newLeft = ui.originalPosition.left + changeLeft / scale_factor;

                var changeTop = ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top;
                var newTop = ui.originalPosition.top + changeTop / scale_factor;

                // apply
                ui.position.left = newLeft;
                ui.position.top = newTop;

        console.log(ui.position)

            },
})
```

As you can see I'm overriding the values within the drag callback inside the draggable to correct calculate the position (dividing by the scale factor)

but when I have a case like in the demo - it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! so It was easier than I thought, simply by multiply both scale values I got it working.

so scale_factor should be 2*2 in the demo.

(the parent container is scaled by 2, and the nested one is scaled by 2 too.)

```
Working fiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MAEvS/672/